# Mocking Kafka APIs for Unit Testing

Tags: unit-testing, go, apache-kafka, confluent-platform

I want to mock the Confluent Kafka APIs for Consumer and Producer in GO for Unit Testing, Is there any way (process/steps/library) to mock them successfully?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: Yes. You should be able to use it as-is in sunny-scenario testing (i.e., messages will produce successfully) with producer applications by simply configuring test.mock.num.brokers=3 in your existing application. Found it from the library.

Comment: https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-go/blob/master/kafka/integration_test.go

Comment: https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-go/blob/master/kafka/consumer_test.go

Answer (score -2):

`producer_test.go` in kafka module has a useful test producer:

```
p, err := NewProducer(&ConfigMap{
    "socket.timeout.ms":  10,
    "message.timeout.ms": 10})
```

https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-go/blob/master/kafka/producer_test.go